# Drupal 7 features module not showing up under structure

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Features module i downloaded from drupal site and installed that module.

I enabled the module also but it is not showing under that structure list where blocks views content types will be there.

I was trying to do export and import data so that features module could help me with that but it is not showing up. I even flushed the cache but still did not work.

I have been using drupal 7, is there anything i should lookup. Please help me with this.

Comment: Hi try to directly reach the features page using the relative path "admin/structure/features". If this is takes u to 404 page then disable the module and uninstall the module. Then enable it again. If the problem persist the please provdie some information regarding other module u may be using like memcache etc.

Comment: Ya i tried to give relative path, but it doesn't show 404 error page but it stays in that structure page where it shows blocks views and all. Other modules i have installed is location, display suite, auto_nodetitle, admin_menu, colorbox, form_builder, gmap, modal_forms,libraries, pages, panels, references, smtp,views

Comment: Then it means the features module has not been installed properly.please uninstall and install again. Then check if u r able to find the url "admin/build/features" and also "admin/structure/features"

Comment: Ya i tried with uninstalling but still it doesn't show up. That admin/build/features lands in administration page where it has dashboard content structure and all.

Comment: when the features module is enabled- see if menu_links table has the links from features module in that table.

Comment: I came to know what was the issue, i was not able to flush the menu as i saw in reports. Because of some wrong coding standards it was affecting this menu.. It is resolved now. Thank you.